# How to hide the all the tabs opened in accordion menu item, when we clicked on specific tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a requirement that when I clicked on any of tab, it is working like accordion menu tabs, but here one problem is when I clicked on any other tab, the opened tab should be closed only current tab related content should display, as html I mentioned is sample only, actually the id's and div's are dynamically generating. I am also inserting the picture in order to understand better.[image]

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"/>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  

 // Get all the links.
 var link = $("#vy_accordion a");
 

 // On clicking of the links do something.
 link.on('click', function(e) {

     e.preventDefault();

     var a = $(this).attr("href");

     $(a).slideToggle('fast');
     
     $(".control-group").css({ 'display' : 'block', 'margin-bottom' : '0' });

     
 });
 
 });
 
 </script>
```

```css
#vy_accordion {
 margin-top: 10px;
 border: thin solid #cecece;
 border-top: none;
 border-bottom: none;
}

#vy_accordion div {
 background: white;
 /*height: inherit;
 line-height: inherit;*/
 display: none;
 border-bottom: thin solid #cecece;
 padding-left: 15px;
 min-height: 70px;
}

a.divlink {
 display: block;
 /* width: 483px; */
 background: #f4f4f4;
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(white, #ededed);
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(white, #ededed);
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(white, #ededed);
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(white, #ededed);
 background-image: linear-gradient(white, #ededed);
 color: #959696;
 padding-left: 15px;
 height: 40px;
 line-height: 40px;
 text-decoration: none;
 border-bottom: thin solid #cecece;
 border-top: thin solid #cecece;
 font-family: Arial;
 font-size: 13px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px white;
}
```

```html
<a class="divlink" href="#Menu-hover-color">Menu-hover-color</a>
<div id="Menu-hover-color" style="display: none;"> 
  <div class="control-group"> 
    <label class="control-label" for="_156_Menu-hover-color"> Menu-hover-color </label> <input class="field" id="_156_Menu-hover-color" name="" type="text" value="#B3E5FC">  
  </div> 
</div>
<a class="divlink" href="#Menu-hover-color">Menu-item-color</a>
<div id="Menu-item-color" style="display: none;"> 
  <div class="control-group"> 
    <label class="control-label" for="_156_Menu-item-color"> Menu-hover-color </label> <input class="field" id="_156_Menu-item-color" name="" type="text" value="#B3E5FC">  
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create fiddle for your working tabs?

Comment: i can't create fiddle sorry all the html is dynamically generating already I provided sample html code how it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add similar class to your tabs (e.g. `linkTab`) and based on this class-selector call `hide()` before showing the clicked / selected tab, as following:

**HTML:**

```
<a class="divlink" href="#Menu-hover-color">Menu-hover-color</a>
    <div class="linkTab" id="Menu-hover-color" style="display: none;">
...
```

**JS:**

```
var link = $("#vy_accordion a");

// On clicking of the links do something.
link.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var a = $(this).attr("href");

    // this line will hide all open tab based on class selector
    $('.linkTab').hide();

    $(a).slideToggle('fast');

    $(".control-group").css({ 'display' : 'block', 'margin-bottom' : '0' });

});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gj9a737h/4/)